# Visual Studio problem connecting Windows and Mac

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, downgrade

I need to connect my Windows with the Mac, but I need the version of visual studio Mac, which can co nnect with the VS version in Windows v16.2.0.

Xamarin.iOS 12.14.0.110 in my Windows VisualStudio

Xamarin.iOS 13.2.0.42 in my Mac (I need to downgrade this version and install the Visual Studio for Mac 8.2 preview 5)

Can anyone help me??

Comment: Make sure to update the version of VS on windows to 16.3.x .It will support Xcode 11.0 and iOS 13.x .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT The problem comes because if I update my windows VS there are things that doesn`t work on Android, and with the iOS project the same

Comment: You can provide the details about the issue after you update the IDE .

Answer (score 0):

An older version of Visual Studio or VS for Mac cannot be installed. There are only release notes for older versions available here: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

The only solution is to go to the latest stable version. To avoid errors, just switch back from preview to the stable build channel of Visual Studio for both Mac and Windows. The preview builds can be unstable, and it can be very difficult to resolve errors.

In the rare event where you are getting a lot of errors in the Stable build channel even after you have deleted all your temporary files (`git clean -fxd`), sometimes Deleting all your VS files and reinstalling VS will always fix the problem.